# How can i multiply values of a column without .apply in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

i am trying to convert each value (USD100-120 e.g.) in a column of my dataset to USD (there are many different currencys like EUR etc.) So based on their Currency i need to convert them with the respective conversion rate.
My input file is something like this:

```
d = {'location': ['US', 'UK'], 'price': ['USD10-20', 'GBP10-20']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

location|price

US      |USD10-20

UK      |GBP10-20

etc.

I tried this :

```
def convertCurrency(price):
    c=CurrencyConverter()
    currency= price[0:3]
    numbers=re.findall(r'\d+',price)
    lowerbound= re.findall(r'\d+',price)[0]
    res=""
    upperbound='x'
    if currency=='USD':
        return price
    if len(numbers)>1:
        upperbound=numbers[1]
    first=int(c.convert(int(lowerbound),price,"USD"))
    if upperbound != 'x':
        second=int(c.convert(int(upperbound),price,"USD"))
        res=''+currency+str(first)+"-"+str(second)
    else:
        res = '' + currency + str(first)
    return res
```

and calling it with apply

```
df['price'] = df.apply(lambda row: convertCurrency(row.price), axis=1)
```

but this takes way too long.
i also tried this:

```
df['price'] = convertCurrency(df['price'])
```

but this will throw an error because the function gets a series object and not a string. What do i have to change or Is there another way?
My desired result will be

location|price

US      |USD10-20

UK      |USD14-28

Comment: Add the sample input / output df please

Comment: Please include a small subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: okay, i tried to provide you with a little example

Comment: can you try `print([x.upper() + ' | '+ y  for x, y in zip(d['location'], d['price'])])` and confirm if this is what you want ?

Comment: no, i need to call the convert function for every value in a column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try using [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) to get usable values then [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) on axis 1:

```py
import pandas as pd
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter

d = {'location': ['US', 'UK'], 'price': ['USD10-20', 'GBP10-20']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

c = CurrencyConverter()
# Extract Values
df[['currency', 'v1', 'v2']] = df['price'].str.extract(r'(\w{3})(\d+)-(\d+)',
                                                       expand=True)
# Mask For Non USD Currency
m = df['currency'].ne('USD')
# Replace price where not USD
df.loc[m, 'price'] = df[m].apply(
    lambda s: f'USD'
              f'{int(c.convert(int(s.v1), s.currency, "USD"))}'
              f'-'
              f'{int(c.convert(int(s.v2), s.currency, "USD"))}',
    axis=1
)
# Drop Added Columns
df = df.drop(columns=['currency', 'v1', 'v2'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  location     price
0       US  USD10-20
1       UK  USD13-27
```